# how to get the location which we are viewing by react native map box?

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl

i want to get the lat and lang of location while moving map

i mean console.log(regain) or something like this

i try  onRegionDidChange but i could not find a way out

```
           <Mapbox.MapView
        styleURL={Mapbox.StyleURL.Street}
        zoomLevel={15}
        onRegionDidChange={this.onRegionDidChange}
        logoEnabled={false}
        showUserLocation={true}
        centerCoordinate



{[parseFloat(this.state.longitude),parseFloat(this.state.latitude)]}
        style={styles.container}>

    </Mapbox.MapView>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You will get values from callback in every methods like onRegionDidChange and onRegionIsChanging etc.**

**Log the value from callback and maybe you will need to stringify it.**

```
  onRegionDidChange={(values)=>{console.log(values)}}

   or

  onRegionIsChanging={(values)=>{console.log(JSON.stringify(values))}}
```

**Inside the `values` there maybe values other than `co-ordinates`**

**Take only what you need** like for if there is a value `lat`(latitude). Get the value as

```
values.lat
```

Comment: i try this but nothing happan in console